# Launch GUI application from local server on remote server without auto start on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, gui

I'm looking for a way to do the following:

- manually launch GUI apps on remote server (no autostarting apps, so no cron/systemd etc)
- not see any GUI on local server (so no ssh -X)

At the risk of over-explaining this, if you want to launch TeamViewer from command-line on remote server, you can `ssh` in and type `teamviewer` in Terminal. This is the output:

```
Init...
xprop:  unable to open display ''
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Starting network process (no daemon)
Network process already started (or error)
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I want to launch TeamViewer on remote from local and have it running but I don't want to see TeamViewer's GUI on local.

**Why don't you use auto-start like cron?**

Because I'm testing my application and its inconvenient to keep rebooting the remote server.

Comment: Try using the IP addr of the REMOTE box and 0.0 for the destop in the DISPLAY variable?  I seem to remember that this was the default behavior back in the day if I didn't set the DISPLAY variable at all but your `unable to open display ''` message makes me think that you might need to set it.

Comment: Some advice: Look in TeamViewer's logfile (perhaps `gui.log`) for useful messages. Check for the file `gui.lock` and if found delete it. If using wayland then try without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Senor CMasCmas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%c3%b1or-cmasmas) suggested, I tried `DISPLAY=:0 teamviewer` and it works!

Generally, its `DISPLAY=:0 APPLICATIONNAME`

If there are any other ways to do this, I'd be happy to consider.